# Canadian citizen (but not resident), do I need an ESTA to travel to the USA from Belgium?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, belgium, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen who lives in Belgium. 
I want to visit NY this summer. Do I need a ESTA waiver for that?

Answer (score 6):

[Canadian citizens do not need a visa to enter the US (with some exceptions).](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/information-for-canadians/canadians-requiring-visas.html) They do not need a visa waiver, and so do not need an ESTA. Residency is not an issue. You will of course need a Canadian passport to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 5):

[The ESTA is only relevant for citizens of Visa Waiver Program countries](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#vwp3), which you are not. Like many other such rules, what matters is your citizenship, not where you currently reside or travel from.

I am not sure of the exact rules for Canadian citizens but I think you don't need any visa or prior formalities for a short visit to the US. The [Timatic database](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=CA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=US&EM=BE&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) confirms this.